# SQL use info from select to insert

Tags: mysql, sql, join, phpmyadmin

I run this code to get a list of users invoice number, address etc.

```
SELECT A.id, A.userid, A.duedate, A.status, B.firstname, B.lastname, B.address1, B.city, B.postcode
FROM tblinvoices A
inner join tblclients B
on A.userid = B.id
WHERE duedate >= '2013-02-18'
AND duedate <= '2013-03-03'
AND A.status = 'Unpaid';
```

But i need to insert some of the information into another table.

Now i manualy run:

```
INSERT INTO `dbuser`.`tblnotes` (`id`, `userid`, `adminid`, `created`, `modified`, `note`, `sticky`) VALUES (NULL, '4585', '1', '2013-03-03 07:05:00', '', 'invoice by mail', '1');
```

How can this be automated?
So all the "userid" which is listed by the first command simply gets added a note saying that it is sent an invoice by mail.

Answer (score 0):

use `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement, ex

```
INSERT  INTO dbuser.tblnotes (id, userid, adminid, created, modified, note, sticky)
SELECT  NULL, A.userid, A.userid, '2013-03-03 07:05:00', '', 'invoice by mail', '1' 
FROM    tblinvoices A
        inner join tblclients B
            on A.userid = B.id
WHERE   duedate BETWEEN '2013-02-18' AND '2013-03-03' 
        AND A.status = 'Unpaid';
```

Note: you must align the values of the select statement on the order of columns in the `INSERT` clause.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with align the values ?.. Is not the best when it comes to and understand English.

Comment: what i mean is don't interchange the values, example, `INSERT INTO tableName(col1, col2, col3) SELECT col1, col2, co3 FROM table2`